# Get URL after redirection

Tags: python, r, rvest, httr

I have a link **https://clk.omgt5.com/?AID=183476&PID=9319&WID=33968** that redirects to **www.fabfurnish.com** which I need as ouput. Below is what I have tried:

```
require(httr)
link <- "https://clk.omgt5.com/?AID=183476&PID=9319&WID=33968"
GET(link)$url
```

Comment: output should be www.fabfurnish.com

Comment: The advertising URL doesn't use traditional redirection, they use javascript redirection so you need to parse the HTML and extract the URL. I was going to post an answer, but am unsure if your final goal is to scrape content from fabfurnish.com. If that is the case you'll be violating two sections of their terms of service and I don't aid content thieves.

Comment: @hrbrmstr dont need the content, just need the url.

Comment: @hrbmstr how could you possibly know what may or may not have been negotiated between the OP and the the owners of the site to claim that the OP is somehow violating the terms of service?